# Pandas: How do I convert a column of time duration in minutes:seconds into datetime when some of minutes are greater than 60?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe column that contains the durations of videos in minutes:seconds. Unfortunately some of the rows are formatted incorrectly where the minutes are greater than 60 (e.g 94:36). When I try to run `pd.to_datetime` using a format string `%M:%S` it gives me an error saying that the aforementioned time is incorrectly formatted.

How do I fix this so that the times are correct (e.g converting the extra minutes into hours? 94:36 -> 1:34:36) for all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of going about it. It currently goes into a new column but you can have it overwrite by changing `'new time'` to just `'time'`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = { 'time': ['15:48','84:52','77:10','10:03'] }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['time'])

min = df['time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
sec = df['time'].str.split(':').str[1].astype(int)
hrs = min//60
min = min%60
df['new time'] = hrs.map(str) + ":" + min.map(str) + ":" + sec.map(str)
print(df)
```